# Should my question be migrated to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, migration

My latest question [How to create an expandable list of blog posts in blogger (similar to the Blog Archive)?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28113/how-to-create-an-expandable-list-of-blog-posts-in-blogger-similar-to-the-blog-a) might better be suited for Stack Overflow, even though the question is relevant to WebApps.  Should it be migrated?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a coding question then it should be asked on Stack Overflow.

However, you really ought to post the code you've tried and what the exact problem is that you are seeing.

Once you have edited your question to include your code, you can then click the `flag` link and request for the question to be migrated by a moderator.